# How to add image to pdf file and print in react native expo

Tags: html, react-native

I want to print a pdf file with an html image embedded on it in react native expo mobile application. And when I tried generating the pdf file, image is not included on the generated pdf file. Any help on how to include image in my pdf file.

```
createPDF = async (html) => {    
      try {
        const {uri} = await Print.printToFileAsync(html);
        Print.printAsync({ uri });
        this.setState({callPrint: false});
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({callPrint: false});
      }
  };

 const html = "
        <html>
            
            <body>
                <div class='title-container'>
                  <img source="asset/omnix.png" />
                   
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    ";
```

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/print/#:~:text=Note%3A%20On%20iOS%2C%20printing%20from%20HTML%20source%20doesn%27t%20support%20local%20asset%20URLs%20(due%20to%20WKWebView%20limitations).%20As%20a%20workaround%20you%20can%20use%20inlined%20base64-encoded%20strings.%20See%20this%20comment%20for%20more%20details. This seems to indicate that the image may not be imported, but I'm not sure

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7940#issuecomment-657111033 This comment is the solution I believe, as images can't be loaded from files directly on iOS

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem on iOS for expo, adding a `fetchImageData` function to convert the image to a Base64 string is the recommended fix

```js
createPDF = async (html) => {...};

fetchImageData = (uri) => { // fetch Base64 string of image data
 const data = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync('file://' + uri, {
  encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
 });
 return imageData = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
};

const html = "
<html>
 <body>
  <div class='title-container'>
   <img source=${fetchImageData('asset/omnix.png')} />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>";
```

If you use `fetchImageData` to fill all your images they will print correctly

Comment: This the response I'm getting from my console [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Location 'file://assets/omnix.png' isn't readable.]. And I am texting on android. please any head way please