# How to print image with PDF file in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm building a mobile application that will be able to print and generate PDF file both android and ios. I am having issues with adding image to it or printing image along with it. When I tried printing or generating PDF, what I only see is the ALT of the image. Please any help on how to go about it?

```
 const copyFromAssets = async (asset) => {
    try {
      await Asset.loadAsync(asset);
      const { localUri } = Asset.fromModule(asset);
  
      return localUri;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw err;
    }
  };


  const processLocalImageIOS = async (imageUri) => {
    try {
      const uriParts = imageUri.split(".");
      const formatPart = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
      let format;
  
      if (formatPart.includes("png")) {
        format = "png";
      } else if (formatPart.includes("jpg") || formatPart.includes("jpeg")) {
        format = "jpeg";
      }
  
      const { base64 } = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
        imageUri,
        [],
        { format: format || "png", base64: true }
      );
  
      return `data:image/${format};base64,${base64}`;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error
    }
  };

  
  const htmlContent = async () => {
    try {
        const asset = require('../../assets/images/unboard3.jpg');
        let src = await copyFromAssets(asset);
        if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            src = await processLocalImageIOS(src);
        }

        return src;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

 const createPDF = async (html) => {    
    try {
      
        const {uri} = await Print.printToFileAsync(html);
        Print.printAsync({ uri });
        // this.setState({callPrint: false});
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        // this.setState({callPrint: false});
    }
};

const html = `
<html>
<body>
  <div class='title-container'>
  <img src="${htmlContent()}" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>`;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image to pdf file and print in react native expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081396/how-to-add-image-to-pdf-file-and-print-in-react-native-expo)

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. both have the same outcome, which is; just showing the ALT in the image. so, I came across this code and looking for a way around it to get it working